# Wordpress external js path not found

Tags: php, wordpress

```
add_action('init','ava_test_init');
function ava_test_init() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'ava-test-js', plugins_url( '/js/ava_test_.js',__FILE__ ));
}
```

I m totally wondering when i see this error

> The requested URL
>   /wordpress/wp-content/plugins/StockExchange/js/ava_test_.js was not
>   found on this server

, I have to try view page source there got my external file but it's give above error.

Comment: same here but nobody can help us

Comment: Is `js` file is available on the server ?